# Why doesn't this plot align to the y-axis?

Tags: plotting

Why is the plot produced by

```
Plot[x + .5, {x, 2*.33*3, 3}]
```

not nicely aligned to the y-axis? 
Or alternatively, why doesn't the y-axis originate at `x=2*.33*3`?

[image]

Comment: Look up `AxesOrigin`

Comment: `AxesOrigin /. Options@Plot[x + .5, {x, 2*.33*3, 3}]`

Comment: `Plot[x + .5, {x, 2*.33*3, 3},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]`

Comment: Why not state these as answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[x + .5, {x, 2*.33*3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
AxesOrigin /. Options @ plot
```

> {2., 2.5}

while the beginning of the plot is set at

```
orig = {2*.33*3, 2*.33*3 + .5}
```

> {1.98, 2.48}

To fix:

```
Plot[x + .5, {x, 2*.33*3, 3}, AxesOrigin -> orig]
```

[image]